# Usando extra field em Annotate Django

Tags: django, django-annotate

Estou tentando adicionar uma coluna chamada `today` em uma Model com o `.extra()`, para trabalhar em um **annotate**. Não estou encontrando. Ele não está encontrando o campo.

```
duration = ExpressionWrapper(F('today') - F('pub_date'), output_field=fields.DurationField()) 
list_posts = posts.extra(select={'today': "now()"}).annotate(duration=duration)
```

**Erro**

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'today' into field.
```

**Observação**
Ele não chega a exibir na lista de possíveis campos o today nem algo parecido.